# Flutter/Dart - Difference between obj!.property and obj?.property

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

In Flutter/Dart their is the null safety feature. In my scenario, I have null safety ON and I am trying to get the property 'myDateTime' of my object MyDateTime . But the compiler produce the error:

```
The property 'myDateTime' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
```

which makes sense because the object can be null.

I tried both solution

```
MyDateTime!.myDateTime
```

and

```
MyDateTime?.myDateTime
```

and the both work fine but I don't understand the difference!! Can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyDateTime!.myDateTime` means: i know `MyDateTime` can never be null and it tries to access property `myDateTime` even if `MyDateTime` is null.

`MyDateTime?.myDateTime` means: i know `MyDateTime` can be null, so if it is, don't try to access property `myDateTime`

The first one returns an error if `MyDateTime` is null, the other one does not.